# php regular expression for 4 characters

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to construct a regular expression for a string which can have 0 upto 4 characters. The characters can only be 0 to 9 or a to z or A to Z.

I have the following expression, it works but I dont know how to set it so that only maximum of 4 characters are accepted. In this expression, 0 to infinity characters that match the pattern are accepted.

```
'([0-9a-zA-Z\s]*)'
```

Comment: FYI those are called "quantifiers"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to match a string that consists *entirely* of zero to four of those characters, you need to anchor the regex at both ends:

```
'(^[0-9a-zA-Z]{0,4}$)'
```

I took the liberty of removing the `\s` because it doesn't fit your problem description.  Also, I don't know if you're aware of this, but those parentheses do not form a group, capturing or otherwise. They're not even part of the regex; PHP is using them as regex delimiters.  Your regex is equivalent to:

```
'/^[0-9a-zA-Z]{0,4}$/'
```

If you really want to capture the whole match in group #1, you should add parentheses *inside* the delimiters:

```
'/(^[0-9a-zA-Z]{0,4}$)/'
```

... but I don't see why you would want to; the whole match is always captured in group #0 automatically.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `{0,4}` instead of the `*` which will allow zero to four instances of the preceding token:

```
'([0-9a-zA-Z\s]{0,4})'
```

(`*` is actually the same as `{0,}`, i.e. at least zero and unbounded.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `{ }` to specify finite quantifiers:

```
[0-9a-zA-Z\s]{0,4}
```

http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid regular expressions completely.

```
if (strlen($str) <= 4 && ctype_alnum($str)) {
   // contains 0-4 characters, that are either letters or digits
}
```

[`ctype_alnum()`](http://php.net/ctype-alnum)